# Combining two bash statements into one

Tags: bash, awk

I hve a number of text files where there is a block of garbage to the left of the useful information. The width of this block keeps changing, so that I calculate the starting column of the useful information using `awk` and then I remove the colums to the left with

```
idx=$(awk '/START/{print index($0,"START")}' in.txt)
idx=$(($idx-3))
colrm 1 $idx < in.txt > out.txt
```

How can I combine the two successive `idx` assignments into one?

Comment: Do you have a shortage of newline characters in your environment? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo  --  Yeah I know this is not really necessary. But it had bothered me that I couldn't find the answer. And I'm grateful for the plenty and quick responses!

Comment: Alternately, don't update the value of `idx`; just use `colrm1 $((idx - 3)) < in.txt > out.txt` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
idx=$(( $(awk '/START/{print index($0,"START")}' in.txt) - 3 ))
```

or:

```
idx=$(awk '/START/{print index($0,"START")}' in.txt); idx=$(($idx-3))
```

Comment: Thanks - the first answer is the one I was really after, and you were a few seconds earlier than @Patrice Levesque.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
idx=$(( $(awk '/START/{print index($0,"START")}' in.txt) - 3 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way would be to use the `END` clause in `Awk` to do an action *after* processing of all the lines end as below. Also a ternary operator to check if the number is not zero would be handy.

```
idx_3=$(awk '/START/{pos=index($0,"START")}END{print pos?(pos-3):0}' in.txt)
```

You can modify the ternary operator to check `pos>=3` also, depending upon your convenience.

Also an even fancier way to do this in `Awk` would be to use its `match()` function and use `RSTART` to mark the record start

```
idx_3=$(awk 'match($0, /START/){pos=RSTART; next}END{print pos?(pos-3):0}' in.txt)
```

[Special built-in variables in Awk](http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_11.html)

Answer (score 1):

The way to really do what you want is to only test for START once and just save it's starting position then print that value minus 3:

```
idx=$(( $(awk 's=index($0,"START"){print s-3; exit}' in.txt) ))
```

The `; exit` is added for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

```
idx=$[$(awk '/START/{print index($0,"START")}' in.txt) - 3]
```

would be enough.

Comment: Thanks - using `[` instead of `((` is something I will study!

Comment: Don't use `$[...]`; it has been deprecated since the late 90s in favor of `$((...))`, and not even documented anymore. I'm not sure why support was never actually removed.

Comment: @chepner Interestingly, the release notes for Bash 2.0 say that the `$[...]` syntax  is no longer supported, but it's still in the source, for whatever reason.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks; your comment led me to discover that `NEWS` and `ChangeLog` do not contain the same information. The change log makes no reference to `$[...]` beyond a parser change  in 2.0-alpha4 to allow nesting. I wonder if it should be re-deprecated in 4.5 so that it can finally be removed in 4.6 (I suspect after all this time, the fear is that anyone still using it has forgotten it was deprecated.)